# Can the failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat security measure be disabled in Electron?

Tags: javascript, security, webgl, electron

When you get WebGL context, you can specify the `failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat` attribute:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('webgl', {'failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat': true});
```

Quote from [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2014/09/12/making-your-webgl-code-more-flexible/) about that attribute:

> Because of the direct access to the GPU allowed by WebGL, browsers must ensure that running your code will not cause a major security issue. For some specific drivers that are not perfectly secure, the browser can prevent hardware acceleration in order to prevent security issues. [...] On these devices, WebGL will software rendering instead, resulting in a slower but safer experience.

Do the security measure can be disabled in Electron easily if I'm not using any external, remote, third-party code in my application?

Comment: there is nothing to disable . if you don't want the browser to fail on slow machines then don't pass `failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat` to `getContext`.

Comment: if you want to disable the GPU blacklist pass `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` via [app.commandLine.appendSwitch](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-access-chrome-flags-in-electron/16470)?

Comment: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the proper quote regarding `failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat` is:

> Context creation will fail if the implementation determines that the performance of the created WebGL context would be dramatically lower than that of a native application making equivalent OpenGL calls.

The paragraph right below the one you quoted states:

> To enforce this, IE has a block-list of drivers that are not safe for
>   use with hardware acceleration. On these devices, WebGL will software
>   rendering instead, resulting in a slower but safer experience.

Chromium(hence electron) has the same feature which can be disabled by setting the #ignore-gpu-blacklist flag:

> Overrides the built-in software rendering list and enables GPU-acceleration on unsupported system configurations.

Note though that these are blacklisted for [reasons](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/gpu/+/master/config/software_rendering_list.json)

Comment: OK, that's now more clear to me. So the feature we're talking about can be disabled by ignoring GPU blacklist, and you are sure about that? Knowing any source that links major performance caveat and GPU blacklist would be great. And the reasons for blacklisting some GPUs other than web security can be found somewhere too?

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful. Would be also great to be able to retrieve these details into JS code Electron, but that's probably not possible, right?